# Finding a file with name that matches current date

Tags: scripts, files

I have a script that creates .csv files with its name matching the current date.

Example: Today's date is *23rd Feb 2017* and when the script runs,it creates a file called `2017-2-23.csv`. This script creates files everyday.

How can I find the file that it creates everyday?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` for this:

```
find -name "$(date +"%F").csv"
```

This command will search for files named `YYYY-MM-DD.csv` using the current date

As @Zanna pointed out in the comments, it seems like you are dropping a leading `0` from the date in your file name. In that case you should use this:

```
find -name "$(date +"%Y-%-m-%-d").csv"
```

Comment: but that will not find OP's file because they dropped they 0 from MM, if their example is correct, so perhaps `find -name "$(date +"%F" | sed 's/-0\?/-/')*"`

Comment: thanks :-) I missed that. I will include it into my answer

Comment: @Zanna "%-m" will omit the leading zero from the month number. So `date +"%Y-%-m-%-d"` will probably give the correct format.

Comment: @Jos TiL that's awesome! thanks. +1 to the revised answer :)